# How to re-enable insecure in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

Since in meteor insecure is enabled by default, I disabled it by typing "meteor remove insecure" in terminal in the app's directory. But when i tried to make it as "insecure" again, it said:

```
$ meteor.bat create insecure
You can't create a Meteor project inside another Meteor project.
```

How do I enable *insecure* again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insecure` is a package. To add pacakges, you use `meteor add [packagename]`. So, inside of your project directory you would run `meteor add insecure`.

That answers your question, but it's my civic duty to recommend using [allow/deny](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow) rules, or [methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods) instead of `insecure`.

Comment: Hear hear! Once you remove insecure it should never come back. It's a *training wheels* package (like autopublish).